# Write a table object into csv in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-table

I have a table object in Matlab with cells as shown in the snapshot:

[image: first entry]

The cells inside Land and Seamark are as below:
[image]

[image]

The class of the objects are as below:

```
>> class(FileData.gTruth.LabelData.Land)
ans =
    'cell'
>> class(FileData.gTruth.LabelData.Land{1,1})
ans =
    'double'
>> class(FileData.gTruth.LabelData)
ans =
    'table'
```

I tried some syntax like `writetable` and `csvwrite` but i am not getting the right format of output. The reading of the Land and Seamark as shown in the figure gets jumbled(reading is columnwise and not row-wise).

I want my output to be in this order:

```
[1063 126 115 86] [1 169 158 147;1 104 165 66;728 105 276 43;950 113 971 40;1 107 810 23;227 133 48 15;618 131 107 20] [562 220 33 51;1736 167 26 28;532 130 18 15;393 129 23 14]
```

Code so far:

`writetable(FileData.gTruth.LabelData,'labelled1.txt','Delimiter' , ';');`

Comment: Please add an example code of what you tried

Comment: `writetable(FileData.gTruth.LabelData,'labelled1.txt','Delimiter' , ';');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [reshape](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) on the transpose of the two-dimensional matrices to build a new table:

```
Ship = [1063 126 115 86]
Land = {[1 169 158 147;1 104 165 66; 728 105 276 43; 950 113 971 40; 1 107 810 23; 227 133 48 15; 618 131 107 20]}
Seamark = {[562 220 33 51; 1736 167 26 28; 532 130 18 15; 393 129 23 14]}

t = table(Ship,Land,Seamark);
t2 = table(t.Ship,reshape(t.Land{:}.',1,[]),reshape(t.Seamark{:}.',1,[]))

writetable(t2,'mycsv.csv','WriteVariableNames',false)
```

The first and only row of `mycsv.csv` file is:

```
1063 126 115 86 1 169 158 147 1 104 165 66 728 105 276 43 950 113 971 40 1 107 810 23 227 133 48 15 618 131 107 20 562 220 33 51 1736 167 26 28 532 130 18 15 393 129 23 14
```

I used the `WriteVariableNames,false` [Name-Value pair](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/writetable.html#namevaluepairarguments) to indicate that the variable names are not to be included in the first row of the file.

Comment: In some of the rows, i have no elements in ship and in seamark so they are empty cells. In such case i get an error: `Error using tabular/verifyCountVars (line 339)
All variables must have the same number of rows.
Error in table (line 276)
                    numRows = tabular.verifyCountVars(vars);
Error in labelled (line 9)
t=table(Ship,Land,Seamark);`
How to handle that?